# nodejs [] operator, avoid picking first char of array of strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, string, foreach

I have an array of strings that sometimes is an array that only contains one string.
when that is the case array[0] does not return the whole string but returns the first char in the string.

I can get around it with some if checking if length is > 1 but it is awful.

is there a safe [] operator or method that always return the whole string in position 0 of the array instead of the first char in the string?

This is an express input-based array in an html form.
I don't really have too much control over how it's generated.

i can't use a foreach as I have other parallel arrays from that form.

Comment: It sounds like when you have only a single string it is not an array, but just the string, so accesssing by index just accesses the char at index of the string. You can either check if `Array.isArray(yourVariable)` or `[].concat(yourVariable)` which will always return an array whether you pass a string or array to concat.

Comment: It sounds like your array is sometimes not an array, but a string itself. (for an array with one element, `array[0]` returns the first element.) To make sure of the type of data you're dealing with, you could use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before operating your var as an array, you should verify that it is an array.

In you case, i guess that when you get only a string the provider of your data return a string type and when there is more than one string it return an array of string.

So you need to verify the type returned by your data provider and then process with the right type.

```
if ( Array.isArray(yourVar) ) {
  console.log('My var is an array');
} else {
  console.log('My var is not an array');
}
```

You can also use typeof to check your var type, for example verify that your var is a string.